# Octagon with defined size

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

for a drawing I need an octagon with a predefined size, actually smaller than the smallest size of the polygon from `shapes.geometric`. Is there another package I could use or an option I'm missing?

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=s,minimum size=0.1mm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=8,red,fill=red,draw]  at (0,0) {};
\draw (0,-5)--(s.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe **scale it**. Tikz offers options for scaling if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Thanks, scale would be an option, however I think Brent.Longborough's solution is the cleaner one.

Comment: @Bernard: Not sure about the "octo" change, as I'm pretty certain, octa as in the greek "oktá" is correct. There is one wiki site about "octagon", no site about an "octogon" and 26M vs 400k Google hits in favor of octagon. If however there is any reason for the "o" in this context I'm happy to learn about it.

Comment: Of course. I was just getting in bed when I wrote this.

Comment: @John Miller: Sorry, you're (partly) right. In my defense, I didn't even try to check, because 1) in French, it's `octo`, and I was pretty sure such words were international; 2) in (ancient) Greek, ‘eight’ is `ὀκτώ` according to Bailly's dictionary, in modern Greek,  it's`οχτώ`.

Comment: @Bernard: No worries, I think in latin it's octo too, and a lot of words have their origin there (eg "octocopter" in the English language). However I think for geometry related words a lot has it's origin in greek, so "ὀκτάγωνον" here, refering to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum size is constrained by the defaults for `text width` and `inner sep`.

Try this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=s,inner sep=0mm,text width=0mm,minimum size=0.1mm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=8,red,fill=red,draw]  at (0,0) {};
\draw (0,-5)--(s.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is exactly what I want.